# Persisting my state between uses

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

Newbie at `netbeans-platform`.

How can I save my state from one execution to the next.

The netbeans platform elegantly remembers the state and position of all my windows. How can I add to that state some of my own data? Very much like Netbeans saves what projects are open and reopens them when it starts up, along with their state.

Ass suggested [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/doc-files/api.html#create-ser) I added the following to my `TopComponent` but it doesn't work. `getPersistenceType` is called but neither `writeExternal` n'or `readExternal` are called.

```
@Override
public int getPersistenceType() {
  return TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS;
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput oo) throws IOException {
  super.writeExternal(oo);
}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput oi) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  super.readExternal(oi);
}
```

Comments [here](https://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic47681.html) suggest tapping into `readProperties` and `writeProperties` but that doesn't feel right to me. I am not wanting to store `Properties`, I want to store `State`.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I blogged about this, using the Session Storage feature of the Swing Application Framework in a NetBeans Platform application:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2009/04/netbeans-platform-meets-swing.html

The following 3 classes should provide the integration into the NetBeans Platform:

- [ModuleApplicationContext.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-util/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/util/modules/ModuleApplicationContext.java)
- [ModuleLocalStorage.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-util/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/util/modules/ModuleLocalStorage.java)
- [Modules.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-util/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/util/modules/Modules.java)

The referenced [XProperties](http://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-util/src/org/jdesktop/appframework/swingx/XProperties.java) and JXTable you only need if you want support for SwingX classes such as JXTable.

To use this feature in your own module you need to initialize the context in your ModuleInstall class:

```
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {  

   private static ModuleApplicationContext applicationContext;  

   @Override  
   public void restored() {  
       applicationContext = new ModuleApplicationContext(Modules.getModuleInfo(  
               Installer.class));  
   }  

   public static ModuleApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {  
       return applicationContext;  
   }  
}
```

For a given contentPane you can then store the GUI session state using:

```
Installer.getApplicationContext().getSessionStorage().save(  
                getContentPanel(), SESSION_STORAGE_XML);
```

and restore the state using:

```
Installer.getApplicationContext().getSessionStorage().  
                restore(getContentPanel(), SESSION_STORAGE_XML);
```

Note: you need to set the component names of the relevant components

You can find the complete sample here: http://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/

Also note however that development of the Swing Application Framework ([JSR-296](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=296)) has been withdrawn.

There is a fork called [Better Swing Application Framework](https://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home), but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: That seems like an incredibly complicated way of doing it. I hope a simpler one has arisen over the past 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with this but finally I could fix it.

Annotate Your topcomponent class with @TopComponent.Description and set the right persistence type inside the annotation. 
Your topcomponent class has to be serializable so,
every fields inside the topcompent have to be serializable or transient. 
You can implement Your custom serialization with readExtern/writeExternal but it is not necessary, You can remove them.
If it still does not work check the log after You closed Your netbeans app and You will see why the platform could not serialize Your topComponent.